# Why does my neural network make such inaccurate predictions after training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I've been working off of a guide I found for making an object classifier. My classifier's job is to determine if the image it's looking at is anime, as I want to integrate it into a bot that will flag anime down in a group chat. The chart the network outputs after training shows decent but improvable results, but the classifying script does not seem to be decently accurate at all. My dataset is 1000 images, [here is the chart of my last training attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaMVO.png). 
As you can see, the val_loss value is fairly workable but turbulent.

I am feeding the trained model 2 images to test it after training and saving weights, an image of a [normal houseplant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oor2j.jpg), and a [generic anime girl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcPg4.jpg). The model predicts 0.37% Anime for the houseplant, and 0.00% Anime for the anime photo. These photos are visually similar to their respective datasets, those being "Anime" and "Other" (which includes images of cars, plants, houses, and other "random" objects). These images are class labeled by their subfolder.

Here is the code for my model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

class SmallerVGGNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes):
        # initialize the model along with the input shape to be
        # "channels last" and the channels dimension itself
        model = Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)
        chanDim = -1
        # if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
        # and channels dimension
        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)
            chanDim = 1


        # CONV => RELU => POOL
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",
            input_shape=inputShape))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

        # (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

        # (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
        model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

        # first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(1024))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))

        # 1 node
        model.add(Dense(1))
        model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

        return model
```

My trainer:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
# import the necessary packages
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from pyimagesearch.smallervggnet import SmallerVGGNet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random
import pickle
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset (i.e., directory of images)")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to output model")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--labelbin", required=True,
    help="path to output label binarizer")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to output accuracy/loss plot")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the number of epochs to train for, initial learning rate,
# batch size, and image dimensions
EPOCHS = 100
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 32
IMAGE_DIMS = (96, 96, 3)
# initialize the data and labels
data = []
labels = []
# grab the image paths and randomly shuffle them
print("Output: loading images...")
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"])))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)

# loop over the input images
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (IMAGE_DIMS[1], IMAGE_DIMS[0]))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)
    # extract the class label from the image path and update the
    # labels list
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    labels.append(label)


    # scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0, 1]
data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)
print("Output: data matrix: {:.2f}MB".format(
    data.nbytes / (1024 * 1000.0)))

# binarize the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,
    labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    # construct the image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=45, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

# initialize the model
print("Output: compiling model...")
model = SmallerVGGNet.build(width=IMAGE_DIMS[1], height=IMAGE_DIMS[0],
    depth=IMAGE_DIMS[2], classes=len(lb.classes_))
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])
# train the network
print("Output: training network...")
H = model.fit(
    x=aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)

    # save the model to disk
print("Output: serializing network...")
model.save(args["model"], save_format="h5")
# save the label binarizer to disk
print("Output: serializing label binarizer...")
f = open(args["labelbin"], "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(lb))
f.close()
```

And lastly, my classifier:

```
import tensorflow
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import pickle
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to trained model model")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--labelbin", required=True,
    help="path to label binarizer")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
output = image.copy()

# pre-process the image for classification
image = cv2.resize(image, (96, 96))
image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
image = img_to_array(image)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

# load the trained convolutional neural network and the label
# binarizer
print("[INFO] loading network...")
model = load_model(args["model"])
lb = pickle.loads(open(args["labelbin"], "rb").read())

# classify the input image
print("[INFO] classifying image...")
proba = model.predict(image)[0]
idx = np.argmax(proba)
label = lb.classes_[idx]

# correct answer
filename = args["image"][args["image"].rfind(os.path.sep) + 1:]
correct = "correct" if filename.rfind(label) != -1 else "incorrect"

# build the label and draw the label on the image
label = "{}: {:.2f}% ({})".format(label, proba[idx] * 100, correct)
output = imutils.resize(output, width=400)
cv2.putText(output, label, (10, 25),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
    0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# show the output image
print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
cv2.imshow("Output", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Some things I've tried include smaller epoch counts, alternatives to sigmoid, different loss functions, and more concrete categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model ends with a single Dense unit with sigmoid activation, however, you later use np.argmax() alongside a list of labels as if you were using softmax activation. You are accidentally predicting whichever class is labeled ”0” for every sample. Your model trained fine, it’s just how you made the predictions afterwards.

Comment: My model isn't as good as it's supposed to be, the stability of that training attempt was apparently anomalous, but that's another problem I can work on. You were right though, that class label was a problem, so that's one less problem I have to work on